# Why added to esp is 0x10?

Tags: assembly, x86, stack, callstack

I'm reading a [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions) article and having a problem of understanding why there's an `add esp, 0x10` at the end of of following code block. I'll spare my own assumptions and simply ask – why?

```
printnums:
    ; stack setup
    push ebp
    mov ebp, esp
    sub esp, 0x08
    mov [ebp-0x04], ecx    ; in x86, ecx = first argument.
    mov [ebp-0x08], edx    ; arg2
    push [ebp+0x08]        ; arg3 is pushed to stack.
    push [ebp-0x08]        ; arg2 is pushed
    push [ebp-0x04]        ; arg1 is pushed
    push 0x8065d67         ; "The numbers you sent are %d %d %d"
    call printf
    ; stack cleanup
    add esp, 0x10
    nop
    leave
    retn 0x04
```

Comment: Because the `caller` of `printf` has to clean up the stack and since 4 32-bit values were pushed on the stack just before printf 0x10 is added to ESP after (0x10 = 16 decimal and 4*4=16). `printf` as part of the _C_ library is presumed to use the _CDECL_ calling convention (caller cleans up)

Comment: This is unoptimized code. If you enable optimization, this would probably go away. Looking at the unoptimized assembly output of a compiler is generally not helpful.

Comment: @MichaelPetch; What are the 4 32 bit values pushed?

Comment: @psprint: The four `push` instructions preceding the `call printf`, which push the four arguments passed to `printf`, each of which is 32 bits (presumably integers or pointers).

Comment: @prl: If we enabled optimization, more likely the `leave` would go away (omit frame pointer) and the `add esp, 0x10` would remain.

Answer (score 5):

It's pointless here because `leave` will restore ESP wherever it's currently pointing.

As Wikipedia says, this is disassembly of GCC output from the C functions shown right above it
(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#Microsoft_fastcall).  We can tell from `__attribute__((fastcall))` that it's not MSVC, and the `nop` and `leave` look like **un-optimized GCC output.**

That's why it stores the 2 incoming register args to stack space, before reloading them with `push`.

The block of code for the function-call statement itself ends by **popping the 4 dword args that are actually passed to printf** (which is cdecl, not fastcall).  That's 0x10 = 16 bytes.

It's not popping the space reserved by `sub esp, 8` for local vars; that's left for `leave`.

You can see the same thing on the Godbolt compiler explorer (https://godbolt.org/z/vdM4cxM7q), and by looking at compiler asm output (instead of disassembly), you can get a symbolic name instead of a numeric address like 0x8065d67.  And more importantly, it will colour-highlight C source lines to match them up with asm lines.

(Actual `gcc -O0 -m32` output uses `sub esp, 24`, not 8.  Maybe the wikipedia output is from an even earlier GCC version.  Or it's from a version of GCC targeting Windows or *BSD where 16-byte stack alignment isn't a requirement for 32-bit code; it seems the space-wasting bug goes away with `-mpreferred-stack-boundary=2`, so GCC5.4 https://godbolt.org/z/KWzK6zdrj exactly reproduces that asm output.  GCC 4.9 and earlier don't waste instructions with a NOP.)